# how to run function in one controller?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my controller

```
.controller('tanyaCtrl', function($rootScope, $ionicPopup, tanyaService, $state) {

    $rootScope.hal=1;
    $rootScope.klikBerikutnya = function() {
        $rootScope.hal=$rootScope.hal+1;
        //how to run next function after this code..?
    }

    //next function
    $rootScope.showData = function() {
    tanyaService.getApiTanya($rootScope.getPilihSubTest, $rootScope.hal).success(function(dataAmbil){
      $rootScope.Questions = dataAmbil;
    });
  };
  $rootScope.showData();
})
```

How to run function in one controller like above..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the function to be executed next as follows:

```
.controller('tanyaCtrl', function($rootScope, $ionicPopup, tanyaService, $state) {

$rootScope.hal=1;
$rootScope.klikBerikutnya = function() {
    $rootScope.hal=$rootScope.hal+1;
    //how to run next function after this code..?
    //just call the function here as follows:
    $rootScope.showData();
}

//next function
$rootScope.showData = function() {
tanyaService.getApiTanya($rootScope.getPilihSubTest, $rootScope.hal).success(function(dataAmbil){
  $rootScope.Questions = dataAmbil;
});
  };
  $rootScope.showData();
})
```